# Django: Add animation to "task" divs, and also trouble with some CSS

Tags: jquery, css, django

I'm a newbie to web development with regards to using a server and jQuery. What I'm creating as an assignment to learning Django before I do my big employment project is simply modifying a web site I had during my job training where we had to implement a "To Do" list with the feature to add tasks. The original site involved using HTML, CSS, and jQuery, with the ability to animate fade-ins and cross out the text whenever I check-marked a task by the checkbox on the left side.

This time, I want to save all the tasks I’m inputting to my Django development server, and then have it send the data back to me once it’s saved there. This was also the first time where I learned on how to do backend development in a website. However, I'm having trouble with creating the hide and fade in animations with jQuery.

Could you please help me out with both?

Let me show you the code (Please excuse me if the code may not be formatted properly):

ToDoList.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gregory Desrosiers (uWaterloo) - To Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/stylesheet.css">
        <script src="static/javascript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/javascript/ToDoList.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="taskInputTextField">Enter a task:</label><br/>
                <input id="taskInputTextField" type="text" class="form-control" value="What task do you have?"><br/>
                <div id="#buttonBlock">
                    <button type="button" id="addTaskButton" class="btn btn-success">Add Task</button>
                    <button type="button" id="removeAllTasksButton" class="btn btn-danger">Delete All Tasks</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="listOfThingsToDo">
            {% include "ListOfTasks.html" %}
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>&copy; 2015 Gregory Desrosiers / University of Waterloo.</footer>
</html>
```

ListOfTasks.html:

```
{% for task in task_list %}
                <div class="checkbox-task"><label><input class="task" type="checkbox" {% if task.task_check_marked %} checked="checked" {% endif %}> {{ task.task_to_do }}</label></div>
{% endfor %}
```

stylesheet.css:

```
h1, footer, button {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    padding: 0px 30% 0px 30%;
}

#listOfThingsToDo{
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.checkbox-task {
    border: 2px dotted blue;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#buttonBlock {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

#removeAllTasksButton {
    float: right;
}
```

ToDoList.js:

```
$(function(){

    $("#addTaskButton").click(function(){
        var taskInput = $("#taskInputTextField").val();
        if (taskInput.length === 0)
        {
            alert("There is nothing entered in the Task input field. Please enter a task before clicking on the \"Add Task\" button.");
            return false;
        }

        $.post("process-request", {new_task: taskInput}, function(html){

            $("#listOfThingsToDo").load(document.URL + ' #listOfThingsToDo');
            $(".checkbox-task:last").hide();
            $(".checkbox-task:last").fadeIn(500);
        });
    });

    $("#removeAllTasksButton").click(function() {
        $.post("remove-all-tasks", null, function(html) {
            $("#listOfThingsToDo").load(document.URL + ' #listOfThingsToDo');
        });
    });

});
```

Before, I did had a hide and fade-in statements for the last element that's part the "checkbox-task" class, but all it does when I click on the "Add Task" button is hide it then appears again almost instantaneously, sort of like a flicker. The hide statement works, but the fade-in statement doesn't.

I also tried using a while statement to keep the jQuery running and execute the hide and fade-in statements as soon as the new task is added by using a comparison for the new task's value, but that resulted in an infinite loop.

If I remove the statements, all I get is adding in a div with the new task, which is the raw mechanic of the site. But I still want to enhance it with animation.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from ToDoList.models import ToDoChecklistTask
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core import serializers

def getSiteTemplate(request):
    return render_to_response("ToDoList.html", {});

"""def hello(request):
    newObject = ToDoChecklistTask(task_to_do = "Hmm", task_check_marked = True)
    return HttpResponse("<p>" + newObject.__str__() + "</p>");"""

@csrf_exempt
def process_request(request):
    newTask = ToDoChecklistTask(task_to_do = request.POST["new_task"], task_check_marked = False)
    newTask.save();
    task_list = ToDoChecklistTask.objects.all()
    data_to_return = serializers.serialize('json', task_list);
    return HttpResponse(data_to_return, 'application/json')
    # return renderAddedTasks(request);

"""def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))"""

def renderAddedTasks(request):
    task_list = ToDoChecklistTask.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("ToDoList.html",{'task_list': task_list}, context_instance = RequestContext(request));

@csrf_exempt
def remove_all_tasks(request):
    task_list = ToDoChecklistTask.objects.all()
    task_list.delete()
    data_to_return = serializers.serialize('json', task_list);
    return HttpResponse(data_to_return, 'application/json')
    # return render_to_response("ToDoList.html",{'task_list': task_list}, context_instance = RequestContext(request));
```

I absolutely do have more code than just this, but I want to see if this is enough information from your perspective first before I edit this question and add the code from my other Django files. However, I don’t think it’s really necessary for me to post them because they aren’t really related to my question about animation or whether or not I’m handling the requests properly.

Next time, I should consider getting some training from people, because so far most of the training for this only came from reading so many websites.

Comment: I am wondering if I should, in my views.py script, add an additional argument in my HttpResponse objects I'm returning with some template code for a Boolean variable that is assigned a value prior to passing it in the constructor. If this is possible, then what I can do is modify my ListOfTasks.html file to include an "if" condition for the last element to hide by CSS, and let jQuery fade it in as soon as the jQuery script detects it.

Otherwise, I honestly don't know. Why would my for loop override the "fade-in" call in my jQuery function?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to understand is that `load`, which is an Ajax call, is *asynchronous*. That means that the Javascript continues executing while the request is being made. In order to do something when the call completes, you pass a *callback function* as a parameter to `load`. jQuery automatically calls that function when the Ajax is finished loading.

```
$("#listOfThingsToDo").load(document.URL + ' #listOfThingsToDo', function() {
        $(".checkbox-task:last").hide();
        $(".checkbox-task:last").fadeIn(500);
});
```

You can see that the hide and fadeIn calls are within the anonymous function, so they will only be executed when the Ajax request is complete.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some insight. I'll try this later, but my director came in and helped me out with this problem; it's now resolved...