# Django: Trouble with updating a BooleanField with my "ToDoChecklistTask" Model

Tags: jquery, django, django-models

I now got a new question. Some of the raw code is from a [question I previously posted,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466310/django-add-animation-to-task-divs-and-also-trouble-with-some-css) with the exception that my views.py file contains a new function called modify_checked_value, and my jQuery file has been modified differently this time to send requests to the server to update the tasks saved there. A line in my URL file has been added and a slight change to a small HTML template snippet I use to render my list has been made too.

This is a problem I’ve discovered five hours ago and tried to fix it up, but still unsuccessful because I am still new to Django. What I have is a “To Do List” that I am saving it in a Django database. I'm using a CharField to represent the task as a string, and a BooleanField to determine if the task is complete (with the option to uncheck if someone finds out later that the task is not finished).

Suppose I have some tasks that don’t have their checkboxes checked, as they are not checked initially when created. When I click on one and print out the QuerySet of the database, I notice that the Boolean value returned from that model is true and thus the **str**() function outputs a “Yes” as part of the output string. When I click on the same checkbox, the Boolean field is supposed to be set to false and hence the __str__function should output a “No” as part of the string.

But it turns out that after checking and unchecking, the task still has its Boolean field set to true and thus when I refresh the page entirely and the template renders the saved tasks, by the time it gets to that task, the label is crossed. The task’s Boolean field is supposed to be false and hence the label should not be crossed.

How do I update my task object in my database to have its Boolean field set to false when I uncheck the checkbox from the browser? So far, whenever I check the checkbox next to my task, that Boolean field will always be true.

Please take a look at my new code and help me out!

ToDoList.js:

```
$(function(){

    $("#addTaskButton").click(function(){
        var taskInput = $("#taskInputTextField").val();
        var newTask = $("<div class=\"checkbox-task\"><label class=\"task\" ><input type=\"checkbox\">" + taskInput + "</label></div>");
        if (taskInput.length === 0)
        {
            alert("There is nothing entered in the Task input field. Please enter a task before clicking on the \"Add Task\" button.");
            return false;
        }

        $.post("process-request", {new_task: taskInput});

//            $("#listOfThingsToDo").load(document.URL + ' #listOfThingsToDo');
            //$("#listOfThingsToDo").append("<div class=\"checkbox-task\"><label><input class=\"task\" type=\"checkbox\">" + data[data.length - 1].fields.task_to_do + "</label></div>");

        $("#listOfThingsToDo").append(newTask);
            $(".checkbox-task:last").hide();
            $(".checkbox-task:last").fadeIn(500);

        $(newTask).change(function(event){
            console.log($(event.target).is(':checked'));

             //$.post("modify-checked-value", {this_checkbox_is_checked: $(event.target).is(':checked'), index_of_element: $(newTask).index()});
                if ($(event.target).is(':checked'))
                {
                    $.post("modify-checked-value", {this_checkbox_is_checked: true, index_of_element: $(newTask).index()});
                    $(event.target).parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
                    $(event.target).attr("checked:\"checked\"");
                }
                else
                {
                     $.post("modify-checked-value", {this_checkbox_is_checked: false, index_of_element: $(newTask).index()});
                    $(event.target).parent().css("text-decoration", "none");
                    $(event.target).removeAttr("checked");
                }


        });
    });

    $("#removeAllTasksButton").click(function() {
        $.post("remove-all-tasks", null, function(data) {
            $("#listOfThingsToDo").empty();
        });
    });

    $('#listOfThingsToDo :checkbox').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log($this.is(':checked'));
        console.log("asdglkadfjglkadfjglkfdajgl");
        console.log($(event.target).parent().parent().index());

        //$.post("modify-checked-value", {this_checkbox_is_checked: $(event.target).is(':checked'), index_of_element: $(event.target).parent().parent().index()});

        if ($this.is(':checked')) 
        {
            $.post("modify-checked-value", {this_checkbox_is_checked: true, index_of_element: $(event.target).parent().parent().index()});
            $(event.target).parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $.post("modify-checked-value", {this_checkbox_is_checked: false, index_of_element: $(event.target).parent().parent().index()});
            $(event.target).parent().css("text-decoration", "none");
            $(event.target).removeAttr("checked");
        }


    });

});
```

views.py: (Additional code only)

```
@csrf_exempt
def modify_checked_value(request):
    checkbox_value = request.POST["this_checkbox_is_checked"]
    print("Checkbox Value: " + checkbox_value)
    checkbox_id = int(request.POST["index_of_element"])
    print(checkbox_id)
    task_to_modify = ToDoChecklistTask.objects.all()[checkbox_id]
    print("Ready to print")

    task_to_modify.task_check_marked = models.BooleanField(default = checkbox_value);
    task_to_modify.save();


    print(ToDoChecklistTask.objects.all())
    data_to_return = serializers.serialize('json', ToDoChecklistTask.objects.all());
    return HttpResponse(data_to_return, 'application/json')
```

ListOfTasks.html:

```
{% for task in task_list %}
                <div class="checkbox-task"><label class="task" {% if task.task_check_marked %} style="text-decoration: line-through"{% endif %} ><input type="checkbox" {% if task.task_check_marked %} checked="checked" {% endif %}>{{ task.task_to_do }}</label></div>
{% endfor %}
```

In case you need to see more code, please tell me which code I'll missing and I'll edit my question accordingly.

EDIT: As requested, here is the code for models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class ToDoChecklistTask(models.Model):
    task_to_do = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    task_check_marked = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        stringToReturn = "Task: " + self.task_to_do + " Is the task done? "
        if self.task_check_marked:
            stringToReturn += "Yes"
        else:
            stringToReturn += "No"
        return stringToReturn
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to follow your code and I can't tell exactly what is going on. But one definite thing that seems problematic is the reliance on an index as the checkbox_id, and then using that value to index into `ToDoChecklistTask.objects.all()`. You don't show your models so I don't know if you have defined any ordering, but it could well be that the db is returning the data in a different order so the indexes don't match up.

Instead, you should specifically use the `pk` value of the object as the checkbox id, and use that when retrieving the item via `ToDoChecklistTask.objects.get(pk=checkbox_id)`.

Comment: I updated my question; I'm simply asking on how to update my task object whenever I uncheck the checkbox (with the effect of removing the line through the label text) so that when I refresh the page, that checkbox remains unchecked and the label is not crossed out.

The ordering I'm using in my website is, every new task I add is always the last in the list. The first task I add is the first task and remains the first task even if I add additional ones.

Comment: I'm using an index to find which task is unchecked so that I can access its Boolean field and set it to false. First task is 0, second task is 1, and so on.

Comment: It's still not a good idea to rely on an ordering, especially when it's not any more complicated to use the pk.

Comment: Do you know how to get the primary key of an object? By the way, I've added the code for the model I'm using; the ID field is not overwritten there. And before I did had "default = False" passed in the parentheses for my BooleanField constructor, but I removed it for some reason that I can't honestly remember.

Would a picture actually help out more?

Comment: Wait a minute; how do I pass the primary key of an object saved in a server through jQuery back? This is something that's confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

I had someone working by my side take a look into this, and we spent about over a couple of hours trying to resolve this; we finally found what the issue was. We decided from there that I updated the way my elements are accessed by their individual primary keys too.

**In the modify_checked_value function, I'm assigning checkbox_value with the value of request.POST["this_checkbox_is_checked"]. I then assign it to my model field task_check_marked. Before, I understood that checkbox_value was a Boolean value. But because I'm using JSON to transmit data between the web browser and the server,** *request.POST["this_checkbox_is_checked"] is actually a string, not a Boolean value as I was expecting.*

**Because checkbox_value was being assigned a string, Python actually evaluated to true and thus this is why I noticed that when I double-click on a checkbox that was initially unchecked and I refresh the page, the check appears in the checkbox.**

The modify_checked_value function now looks like this and thus the site is working as it should:

```
@csrf_exempt
def modify_checked_value(request):
    checkbox_value = request.POST["this_checkbox_is_checked"]
    checkbox_id = int(request.POST["id_of_element"])
    task_to_modify = ToDoChecklistTask.objects.get(id = checkbox_id)

    task_to_modify.task_check_marked = (checkbox_value == "true")
    task_to_modify.save()

    data_to_return = serializers.serialize('json', ToDoChecklistTask.objects.all());
    return HttpResponse(data_to_return, 'application/json')
```

Anyway, unless you think it's necessary, I won't post the rest of the code because it takes too much time.