# Visualize link has been clicked or not

Tags: python, html, django

I'm currently working on a web app in which I would like to display to the user whether they have visited the link already or not.

The code that displays the links is fairly simple, as seen below.

```
<ul>

    <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://amazon.com">amazon</a></li> 

</ul>
```

What I would like is to visualize that a link has been clicked by just adding a checkmark, or something along those lines, to the right of the link. How would I go about doing that? I'm working with Django for this project so a Django-specific solution would be great.

Comment: is the project base in python ?

Comment: I haven't used django before, does it use jinja?

Comment: @dper yes, it is indeed.

Comment: @Filip I believe it can make use of it yes.

Comment: @MennoVanDijk Did you try using the animation on the click call. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466310/django-add-animation-to-task-divs-and-also-trouble-with-some-css

Comment: How about CSS and the :visited pseudo selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/

Comment: @dper Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. First time looking at Javascript, though, so hard to follow along.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple technique would be to use CSS `:visited` selector (if you don't want to use JavaScript). Check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) for how you can use this selector in CSS.

You can basically add a checkmark in your HTML and set it's `color` same as background color (so that it doesn't show up). And, then change it to some other color when the link is visited. Check out the attached snippet.

```css
a span {
  color: white;
}

a:visited span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li><a href="http://google.com">google<span>&#10003;</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://facebook.com">facebook<span>&#10003;</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://amazon.com">amazon<span>&#10003;</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: The issue with this is that by putting it inside the href tag it shows up as blue (because it is an href) no matter whether you clicked it or not.

Comment: You can add custom styles for the checkmark by using `a span` selector in css.

Comment: This is indeed what I did: https://gyazo.com/64a4f09406649d0a02ee1357d560880f

Comment: I would not expect it to work like that. Maybe, it is getting override by some other code? Because if you run the attached snippet, it will show the checkmark in black (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Django before, but I have some websites using Flask, so I can understand a few parts. I'll add my answer in Flask and hopefully you can translate that into Django. Sorry about that :/

I think you can make this work by using Jinja and some simple HTML.

I made some changes because links will just redirect you outside of your page, so your checkmarks wont be seen

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <button name="google_" value="Google">Google</button>{% if _google %}✔{% endif %}
            <br>
        <button name="fb_" value="Facebook">Facebook</button>{% if _fb %}✔{% endif %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the code in Flask would look like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get("google_", False) == "Google":
            _google = True
            return render_template("test.html", _google=_google)
        elif request.form.get("fb_", False) == "Facebook":
            _fb = True
            return render_template("Test.html", _fb=_fb)
    return render_template("Test.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="localhost", port=5000)
```

Screenshots:

[image: buttons]

[image: google]

[image: facebook]

I didn't really made it look nice but it works :/

Again sorry for making it into Flask. I don't have any experience with Django.